# The probability of choosing Green?

Tags: probability

A box contains $8$ green and $4$ blue marbles. two marbles are selected (at once with no replacement).

Question: find the expected number of green marbles among selected ones.

The answer to is question is $4/3$. However, I got the answer $3/4$ because when you make a tree diagram, you can see that $3/4$ results have green in it since it can either be $\text{GG}$, $\text{GB}$, or $\text{BG}$.

Can anyone explain to me then why it's $4/3$ or is there just a mistake?

Comment: The title "probability of choosing green" is different from the question "expected number of green marbles".

Answer (score 3):

You can build the law of the random variable $X = $ number of green marbles. It is
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
X&0&1&2\cr
\hline
p&\frac{3}{33}&\frac{16}{33}&\frac{14}{33}\cr
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Hence the expectation
$E(X) = 0 .\frac{3}{33}+ 1.\frac{16}{33}+ 2.\frac{14}{33} = \frac{4}{3}$

Note that
$$
P(X=0) = \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{12}{2}}=\frac{3}{33},\quad
P(X=1) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{12}{2}}=\frac{16}{33},\quad
P(X=2) = \frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{12}{2}} = \frac{14}{33}
$$

Answer (score 3):

You received a proper answer to your question allready.

Here I promote another way to find the expectation.

---

Give the selected marbles numbers $1,2$.

For $i=1,2$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if marble $i$ is green, and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $X:=X_1+X_2$ equals the number of green selected marbles.

With linearity of expectation and symmetry we find: $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E(X_1+X_2)=\mathbb EX_1+\mathbb EX_2=2\mathbb EX_1=2P(X_1=1)=2\cdot\frac8{12}=\frac43$$

---

No need here to find the distribution.

Comment: This is nice. There may be a missing explanation: each marble has the same probability to be chosen as the $i$-th one, hence $1/12$. It implies that $E(X_i) = 8/12$. It generalizes to more marbles chosen.